# Login failed using Express and Sequelize with SQL Server

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to use Sequelize (v 5.21.13) to connect to my SQL Server database in my Expressjs app.

dbconfig.js

```
var dbConfig = {
    server: process.env.DB_HOST,
    authentication: {
        type: 'default',
        options: {
            userName: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
            password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD
        }
    },
    options: {
        database: process.env.DB_NAME
    }
};

module.exports = dbConfig;
```

index.js:

```
const dbConfig = require('./dbConfig');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const connection = new Sequelize(
    dbConfig.options.database,
    dbConfig.authentication.options.userName,
    dbConfig.authentication.options.password,
    {
        host: dbConfig.server,
        dialect: 'mssql',

    }
);

connection.sync().then(() => {
    console.log('Connected!');
}).catch((e) => {
    console.log('Error:\n', e);
});
```

Now the thing is that each time I run the server, I get this error

> AccessDeniedError [SequelizeAccessDeniedError]: Login failed for user 'master'.

I have also tried adding additional properties to the new Sequelize() like the following with no luck.

```
dialectOptions: {
    instanceName: 'instance',
    options: {
        encrypt: true,
        trustServerCertificate: true,
        requestTimeout: 30000
    }
}
```

I even tried changing the password to a very simple one with no special characters, connection with Datagrip works after changing but not using Sequelize.

Everything on the dbconfig object is correct so I don't see what the issue might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I was putting the the db instance id as the database name, I realized that the database name was different. Changed it and I'm now connected through Sequelize.